# Magento Easy Responsive Banner Slider by Bassiwebs not working in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Magento Easy Responsive Banner Slider by Bassiwebs and i can't get the banner slider on my homepage . 
I have tried this code for slider .

```
{{block type='imageslider/imageslider' template='imageslider/imageslider.phtml'}}
```

But still it doesn't show the banner slider .

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue with block white listing, for that

Please go to

`System->permission->blocks`

and click on `addnewblock`  add your block `imageslider/imageslider` and set `enable` in dropdown and then click on `save`.

clear your cache and try again